# cannot retrieve input field value using PHP $_POST array

Tags: php, javascript, dom

I cannot get the `$_POST['value']` after form submission.

I have used javascript to assign a value to an input field.
code:

```
function updateValue(pid, value){
    // this gets called from the popup window and updates the field with a new value
    document.getElementById(pid).value = value;
}
```

The above function is called by a popup widow to assign a value to my input field: `pid`

Here is the `form` script:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="project_name" id="pid" disabled="disabled" />
  <input type="submit" id="search" name="search" value="Search" />
</form>
```

In my test.php, I have done:

```
include 'functions.php'; //Has the connection script
if (isset($_POST['search'])){
    echo $project_id = $_POST['project_name'];
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * from item
                    where category like '$project_id %'
                    ");
    echo $num = mysql_num_rows($sql);   
}
```

But I am getting the error: `Undefined index: project_name`

Comment: add the results of `print_r($_POST)`, placed at the beginning of your php script please.

Comment: ah, i didn't see your "disabled" attribute...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disabled inputs doesnt post. Use `hidden` input like this:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="project" disabled="disabled" />
  <input type="hidden" name="project_name" id="pid" />
  <input type="submit" id="search" name="search" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Comment: -1: this don't work with the current script. project name will always be empty with this code.

Comment: @Bora I did that `<input type="hidden" name="project_name" />`
But in my php page, its not `echoing`.
I mean `echo $_POST['project_name'];` is not showing anything.

Comment: updated with added `id="pid"`. You set input value that has id is PID  with js

Comment: @Bora
This was really helpful. One more thing, How can I print the value of the field `<input type="text" name="project" disabled="disabled" />`?
Because after I am setting its value, It needs to be shown on screen.

Comment: If after submit form use `$_POST` like `value="<?php echo $_POST['project_name']; ?>"`. If before submitting, use javascript. But id have to be unique, so you need two times PID input text and hidden. If you use `class="pid"` and update js with class, you set input value before submit form

Comment: No, before submitting, when I am populating `<input type="text" name="project_name" id="pid" disabled="disabled" />` using:
 `document.getElementById(pid).value = value;`
I I use `id="pid"` in the `hidden` field, then how can I see the value of the disabled input tag?

Comment: use `class="pid"` for both input. And set with `document.getElementsByClassName`

Comment: @Bora
Is this valid?:
`document.getElementsByClassName('name').value = value;`
Because its not working in my case.

Comment: You should like : `document.getElementsByClassName('pid')[0].value = value;` or with `querySelector` like this: `document.querySelector('.pid').value;`

Answer (score 2):

Try filling the hidden field when you set the value into disabled field

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="project" id="pid" onchange="document.getElementById("pid-new").value=document.getElementById("pid").value" disabled="disabled" />
      <input type="hidden"  id="pid-new" name="project_name" />
      <input type="submit" id="search" name="search" value="Search" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

your project_name input field is disabled.
remove this attribute then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

It's because disabled attributes aren't passed along the form requests.

If you're setting the value through javascript, and that part works, replace your text input with this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="project_name" id="pid" />
```

this will work